# Prove that this differential equation has a unique solution defined on $\Bbb{R}^+$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

We consider the following O.D.E
\begin{align}(a)\qquad\qquad\begin{cases}x'(t)=\dfrac{\rho^2(x(t))}{1+\rho^2(x(t))} & t\geq 0,\\x(0)=x_0\in \Bbb{R}&\end{cases}\end{align}
where \begin{align}\rho:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}\end{align} is a $C^1$ function. I want to prove that $(a)$ has a unique solution defined on $\Bbb{R}^+?$

**CURRENT PROOF**

Since $\rho:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ is $C^1$ function, $\rho^2$ is also a $C^1$ function. Also, 
\begin{align}\dfrac{\rho^2}{1+\rho^2}\end{align}
is a $C^1$ function.
\begin{align}\rho^2(x(t))\leq 1+\rho^2(x(t)),\;\;\forall\,t \geq 0,\;x\in \Bbb{R}\end{align}
\begin{align}f(x(t))=\dfrac{\rho^2(x(t))}{1+\rho^2(x(t))} \leq 1,\;\;\forall\,t \geq 0,\;x\in \Bbb{R}\end{align}

This implies that $f$ is affine. So, $(a)$ has a unique maximal solution on $[0,t_{\max})$ and $t_{\max}=+\infty$. Therefore, $(a)$ has a unique solution defined on $\Bbb{R}^+?$

Kindly confirm if this proof is fine or not. If no, alternative proofs will be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "affine"? I would call that sub-linear, or bounded growth, or perhaps affinely bounded.

Comment: $f$ is affine if $\exists\,a,b\geq 0$ s.t. \begin{align}\Vert f(x)\Vert \leq a \Vert x\Vert+b,\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb{R}^n \end{align}

Comment: Okay, as said, I would call that differently as "affine" has a strong use in linear algebra. In all, your proof is correct. You could make the bound explicit in $x_0\le x(t)\le x_0+t$.